# how do i count up when there is a unique value but when there is a duplicate value the count remains the same

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, backend

| Question_id | Question | part_model_ans | part_total_marks | answer_mark | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | What's a potato | It's a vegetable | 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 16 | What's a potato | It's a seed | 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 16 | 4+4 | 8 | 2 | 5 | 2 |
| 17 | What's a dog | It's a mammal | 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 17 | What's a dog | It's a pet | 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 17 | 8+8 | 16 | 2 | 5 | 2 |

```
SELECT Q.question_id,Q.question, PMA.part_model_ans,QP.part_total_marks,MA.answer_mark
  DENSE_RANK()  over(Partition by QP.question_id) as number FROM "QUESTIONS" Q
            LEFT JOIN "QUESTIONS_PART" QP ON QP.question_id = Q.question_id
            LEFT join "PART_MODEL_ANSWER" PMA ON PMA.part_id = QP.part_id
            LEFT join "MODEL_ANSWER" MA ON MA.question_id = Q.question_id
            ORDER BY Q.question_id ASC
```

What i would like to do is increase the count when there is a unique question but when there is a duplicate question the count remains the same, the count also resets after every question, i tried using dense rank but it makes the value for all in the column `number` as 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables are unordered sets, so for this to work you need a column that defines the order of the rows so that you can check in that order if the value of the column `Question` changes or not.
I don't see such column in your sample data, so I will use SQLite's `rowid`.

Create a CTE that will return a column `flag` which will indicate if a row is the start of a new `Question`.
Finally use `SUM()` window function to get the result that you want:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT Q.Question_id, Q.Question, PMA.part_model_ans, QP.part_total_marks, MA.answer_mark, Q.rowid, 
         Q.Question <> LAG(Q.Question, 1, '') OVER (PARTITION BY Q.Question_id ORDER BY Q.rowid) flag
  FROM QUESTIONS Q
  LEFT JOIN QUESTIONS_PART QP ON QP.question_id = Q.question_id
  LEFT JOIN PART_MODEL_ANSWER PMA ON PMA.part_id = QP.part_id
  LEFT JOIN MODEL_ANSWER MA ON MA.question_id = Q.question_id
)
SELECT Question_id, Question, part_model_ans, part_total_marks, answer_mark, 
       SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY Question_id ORDER BY rowid) number
FROM cte
ORDER BY question_id
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ec69e0c0bdf95782b2be6aac327fc212).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but i would like to ask could you please explain to me this line of code
(Q.Question <> LAG(Q.Question, 1, '') OVER (PARTITION BY Q.Question_id ORDER BY Q.rowid) flag )
more in detail, i would like to know the specifics of it

Comment: @IDon'tGetIt LAG() returns the value of Q.Question in the previous row and it is compared to Q.Question of the current row. If they are different the result is 1 and if they are the same it returns 0.  This is the column `flag` of the subquery. Check it here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2b9f8b06fe543f32f62f851ae44c3ff8

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `order by`, not `partition by`:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY QP.question_id) as number
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to order by Question, that way the window function will differentiate between questions ([SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5jM6qVx373tvujSUr5b1pS/0) for further reference):

```
SELECT 
    Question, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Question) AS ranker
FROM your_data;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Question          ranker
----------------- ------
"4+4"             1
"8+8"             2
"What's a dog"    3
"What's a dog"    3
"What's a potato" 4
"What's a potato" 4
```